# I granted all privileges to a table to a user, but still get "permission denied"

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

I created a role `read_role` via pgAdmin:

```
CREATE ROLE read_role WITH
NOLOGIN
NOSUPERUSER
INHERIT
NOCREATEDB
NOCREATEROLE
NOREPLICATION;
```

and gave it permissions on my schema

```
alter default privileges in schema intgr grant SELECT on tables to read_role ;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA intgr TO read_role ;
```

Then I create a user via pgAdmin and made it member of `read_role`:

```
CREATE ROLE user WITH
LOGIN
NOSUPERUSER
INHERIT
NOCREATEDB
NOCREATEROLE
NOREPLICATION
ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '';

GRANT read_role TO user WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

And when I login with this user and try to select from that table, it returns me "permission denied".

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the permissions on the schema itself; a frequent omission:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA intgr TO read_role;
```